# In Powerpoint - browse window not displaying all information

Tags: excel, powerpoint, save-as-template

In Powerpoint, Excel (native app, not web version) when I attempt to open files following the path:File >> Open >> Browse >> Sharepoint Pinned Folder ... the file names are missing, covered by a white box.  Note, the screenshot below also displays this issue when saving a file.

This happens when I have multiple files open at the same time.    The files themselves are there and I can click on each one to preview the file name in the File Name field, but it is time consuming and doesn't always work.  How do I prevent this from happening so that I can continue working on multiple files at the same time?

[image]